# Passing value to other component Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

how can I change  value of validCompo from other component please?
Some people speak about Angular service to resolve that, but i don't understand how it works.. I have tried lot of things but nothing works...

Is it possible to show me on the example below the good way to resolve ?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sc7zsc

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `I have tried lot of things but nothing works` Elaborate, what did you try and what didn't work.

Comment: You can use Observables for it, but for suggest more correct way you should explain in details what should you do

Comment: I want to change the value of ValidCompo in AppComponent when i click on the button in CompositionComponent..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the variable defined in the service. Inject the service in both components. In the event handler, update the variable in service, it will reflect in both places.

Comment: for the moment i have this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sc7zsc
I have a bug but i m on the good way?

Comment: You are close.I've forked your app, see the updated code.: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkvijb

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Subject`. Be aware that you can use `@Input` too to achieve this.

Anyway, this is a simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vts7zd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.component.ts

Here's the code:

Main component

```
export class AppComponent  {
  isEnglish = true;
  constructor(private service: CommonService){ }

  setLang(){
    this.isEnglish = !this.isEnglish;
    (this.isEnglish) ? this.service.setLang('IT') : this.service.setLang('EN');
  }
}
```

Service

```
@Injectable()
export class CommonService{
  private lang$ = new Subject<string>();
  public langEvent = this.lang$.asObservable();

  public setLang(lang){
    this.lang$.next(lang);
  }
}
```

Test component that handle the changes

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit  {
  lang ="default";
  constructor(private service: CommonService, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.service.langEvent
    .subscribe(res => {
      if(!!res){
        this.lang = res;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Since this is a code I've did few times ago, you can ignore the `OnPush` strategy along the `ChangeDetectionRef`.

Answer (score 0):

In CompositionService create a variable  validCompo = true.

Inject this service in both the component. and set the variable to accept value from service.
validCompo = this.compositionService.validCompo;

Now you can toggle the value using button click in changeValue() in any component.